How to ignore ENOENT in the backtrace
I added backtrace output for all SIGSEGVS, but I see that ENOENT is not ignored.
how can I ignore these messages so that they are not in Debug?
My code:
signal(SIGHUP,term);
signal(SIGSEGV, print_backtrace);
prctl( PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGHUP);



static void print_backtrace(int err)
{
  LOGE("%s", strerror(err));

  int i, size;
#define ARR_LEN 20
  void* arr[ARR_LEN];
  char **str;

  size = backtrace(arr, ARR_LEN);

  if (!size || size > ARR_LEN) {
    LOGE("\n > OOM or BACKTRACE STRING IS EMPTY");
    return;
  }

  str = backtrace_symbols(arr, size);
  if (!str) {
    LOGE("\n CANT GET BACKTRACE SYMBOLS");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      LOGE("\n [backtrace %d] %p", i, arr[i]);

  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      LOGE("\n [backtrace %d] %s", i, str[i]);

    free(str);
  }

  sleep(10);
}

Debug:
00:54:59 [EE]  main.c:  37: Resource temporarily unavailable: No such file or directory
00:54:59 [EE]  main.c:  60: [backtrace 0] /usr/lib/erlang/lib/gvrp-0.1/priv/gvrp(zloop_start+0x224) [0xy
00:54:59 [EE]  main.c:  60: [backtrace 1] [0x39353a]: No such file or directory
